# Error Using Flows - Required Field Missing

Tags: error, visual-workflow, process

I am attempting to create an automation that populates opportunity contact roles when contacts are selected by the user creating the opportunity.

Upon pushing the flow live, I am getting the following error:

> An error occurred at element Create_Contact_Role_for_Ecommerce (FlowRecordCreate).
>   INSERT --- INSERT FAILED --- ERRORS : (REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING) Required fields are missing: [OpportunityId, ContactId]

what do I need to add the Variable Fields so they are no longer missing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have any values assigned to `OpportunityId` and `EcommerceContactId` variables?

Comment: Ah, that is what is missing. 

I want it to pull the contact in?  Do I use Contact email for that and Opportunity ID? 

It doesn't look like generic Contact is an option.

Comment: What do you mean by "pulling contact in"? You said that you have users to select contact - you just use the selected contact record Id

Comment: My end goal is for users to select a contact and that contact to sync as the opportunity contact role using this flow & a corresponding process.

Comment: is this a flow interview with user input? or is it started as a result of a standard or VF page SAVE on Opportunity via Process Builder?  If latter, your flow will need to query for the `Opportunity.ECommerceContactId` if flow receives only Opportunity.Id as argument

Comment: You should check out the automation hour recording: https://success.salesforce.com/0D53A00002yPuWb  he walked through this very example and even made an app package you could download and re-use.

Answer (score 0):

You can create SObject variable like `ContactObj` and assign that value as default to the `EcommerceContactId` variable.

[image: Flow variable assignment]

And before creating `Opportunity Contact Role` you should make sure the values of `Opportunity Id` and `Contact Id` must be available