# Error in flow : An unhandled fault has occurred in this flow

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, visual-workflow, screen-flow

[image]i am new in salesforce . i am trying to create Salesforce Flow Where after creating a record it redirects to that particular record detail page.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6FB5.png)

[image]

Comment: Like the error suggests, it looks like the required field on the contact object i.e., Lastname is not being populated.Related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155334/error-using-flows-required-field-missing

Comment: @swetha - you should make this the answer

Comment: Sure @cropredy. Just did

Answer (score 1):

As the error message suggests, it looks like the required field on the contact object i.e., Lastname is not being populated which is why the flow is failing.

I recommend reviewing this related [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155334/error-using-flows-required-field-missing)